# IntersectionObserver: Trigger event when scrolling back to the top

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, intersection-observer

I am starting to use the IntersectionObserver API and could create some basic animations, which includes hiding and appearing of elements. However, once a person wants to scroll back to the top, the elements which disappeared by one of the triggers are not getting visible again.

**My Solution so far**

So I thought I might create another test variable within the intersection observer callback function (the `stepI` and `stepII` variable in my code), which checks if the callback function was previously triggered. If so, instead of disappearing the elements, let them appear again.

**My current problem**

So let's say a background image (`id="hiddenImg"`) should appear when the first text block (`id="I"`) passes the 50% border of the viewport and it disappears when the second text block (`id="II"`) enters this area. Even though the image is getting visible again when scrolling back up, if the user does not scroll back completely (so that the second text block goes out of the viewport) and then scrolls back to the bottom, the disappearing trigger of that second text block is not called. This would mean that the background image would stay visible, which it shouldn't.

Here is the js part:

```
var stepI = false;
var stepII = false;

// list of options
    let options = {
      rootMargin: '0px 0px -50%' //WHEN reaching half of the viewport
    };

// instantiate a new Intersection Observer  
"use strict";

var intersectionObserver = new IntersectionObserver(function (entries, observer) {
  entries.forEach(function (change) {
      if (change.isIntersecting) {
          if (change.target.id == "I") {
            $("#hiddenImg").removeClass("hidden_img");
            $("#hiddenImg").addClass("visible_img");

            stepI = true;

            observer.unobserve(change.target);
          } 


          if (change.target.id == "II") {
              if (stepII == false) {
                  $("#hiddenImg").removeClass("visible_map");
                  $("#hiddenImg").addClass("hidden_map");

                  stepII = true

              } else {
                $("#hiddenImg").removeClass("hidden_map");
                $("#hiddenImg").addClass("visible_map");

                stepII = false;
              }
          }
      } 
    });
},options);

// list of paragraphs
let elements = document.querySelectorAll(".stepper");

for (let elm of elements) {
  intersectionObserver.observe(elm);
}
```

Here is my complete code:

```
<html>
<head>
<!-- Load the polyfill. -->
<script src="/js/intersection-observer.js"></script>

<script src='https://unpkg.com/intersection-observer@0.5.0/intersection-observer.js'></script>

</head>
<body>
<style>
    .intro-imgs {
display: block;
margin: 0 auto; /* Will not center vertically and won't work in IE6/7. */
left: 0;
right: 0;
position: fixed;
position: expression(fixed);
}

.hidden_img {
visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
-ms-transform: scaleX(0); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform: scaleX(0); /* Safari 3-8 */
-o-transform: scaleX(0);
-moz-transform: scaleX(0);
transform: scaleX(0);
-webkit-transition: visibility 0s 0.5s, opacity 0.5s linear, -webkit-transform 0.5s;
-moz-transition: visibility 0s 0.5s, opacity 0.5s linear, -moz-transform 0.5s;
-o-transition: visibility 0s 0.5s, opacity 0.5s linear, -o-transform 0.5s;
transition: visibility 0s 0.5s, opacity 0.5s linear, transform 0.5s;
}

.visible_img {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
-ms-transform: scaleX(1); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform: scaleX(1); /* Safari 3-8 */
-o-transform: scaleX(1);
-moz-transform: scaleX(1);
transform: scaleX(1);
-webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s linear, -webkit-transform 0.5s;
-moz-transition: opacity 0.5s linear, -moz-transform 0.5s;
-o-transition: opacity 0.5s linear, -o-transform 0.5s;
transition: opacity 0.5s linear, transform 0.5s;
}

.stepper{
        max-width: 70rem;
    margin: 550px auto 600px auto;
    width: 90%;
    background-color: rgba(248, 248, 248, 0.95);
    font-family: "Helvetica";
    font-size: 17px;
    line-height: 26px;
    padding: 15px;
}
</style>

<!--HTML-->
  <div class="headline">
        <img id="hiddenImg" class="hidden_img intro-imgs" src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/funny-portrait-hero-260nw-410898763.jpg" >
  </div>
  <div id="I" class="stepper">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
  </div>
  <div id="II" class="stepper">
    <h1>THE HEADLINE</h1>
  </div>

<!-- SCRIPT-->
<script>
var stepI = false;
var stepII = false;

// list of options
    let options = {
      rootMargin: '0px 0px -50%' //WHEN reaching half of the viewport
    };

// instantiate a new Intersection Observer  
"use strict";

var intersectionObserver = new IntersectionObserver(function (entries, observer) {
  entries.forEach(function (change) {
      if (change.isIntersecting) {
          if (change.target.id == "I") {
            $("#hiddenImg").removeClass("hidden_img");
            $("#hiddenImg").addClass("visible_img");

            stepI = true;

            observer.unobserve(change.target);
          } 


          if (change.target.id == "II") {
              if (stepII == false) {
                  $("#hiddenImg").removeClass("visible_map");
                  $("#hiddenImg").addClass("hidden_map");

                  stepII = true

              } else {
                $("#hiddenImg").removeClass("hidden_map");
                $("#hiddenImg").addClass("visible_map");

                stepII = false;
              }
          }
      } 
    });
},options);

// list of paragraphs
let elements = document.querySelectorAll(".stepper");

for (let elm of elements) {
  intersectionObserver.observe(elm);
}
</script>
</body>
```